# Is a Primality test Using Wilson's Linear?

Tags: computational-complexity, primality-test

I think we require $n-1$ multiplications, after each of which we are allowed perform a $mod n$ operation, thus not blowing up in memory. We may finish earlier but maximally $2(n-1)$ calculations are required.

Is this correct?

Comment: Not a useful test, though. Trial division to $\sqrt n$ - which is not quick enough for large numbers - is way better than using Wilson's theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algorithmic complexity is normally measured in terms of the size of the input, i.e. the amount of memory it takes to store. For primality testing -- or anything where the input is an integer -- this is the number of bits of the integer, i.e. roughly $\log_2 n$. In those terms, this algorithm is exponential.

Comment: Yes but not if we take the modulo after each multiplication right? Then the size of the bits always stays lower than the size of the bits for n?

Comment: Aha, apologies, I just understood your argument. Thanks!